# How to judge whether the relaychain of a parachain is polkadot or kusama or westend?

Tags: parachain

Is it possible to query through state storage or rpc?

Comment: Can you be more specific about where the query is happening? For example, are you trying to write code for your parachain which has it understand which relay chain it is connected to?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Not a parachain, I want to query use polkadot.js

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I know of, either through RPC or querying chainstate.

### RPC

Make a `system.chain` call via RPC and it will return the chain name in plain text.

Example:

Polkadot

### Chainstate

If you query chainstate ( https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/chainstate ), for `system.lastRuntimeUpgrade`, you'll get the current runtime version and the name of the chain.

Example:

```
{
  specVersion: 9,260
  specName: polkadot
}
```

Comment: I think he is asking querying from a parachain, to know which relay chain it is connected to, not from the relay chain itself.